# How to delete the first item in my list?

Tags: c, linked-list

I am building a function that should delete a item in a linked list. My problem is that I could delete any element but not the first one, why is that?

My object file:

```
typedef struct list {
    char *key;
    char *value;
    struct list *next;
} List;

void db_init(List *list) {
    list = malloc(sizeof(db_sizeOfStruct()));

    list->next = NULL;
    list->key = NULL;
    list->value = NULL;
}

void db_delete(char *key, List *list) {
    List *prev;
    db_init(prev);
    int first = 1;

    while(list != NULL) {
        if(strcmp(key, list->key) == 0) {
            if(first == 1) {
                list = list->next; // This is supposed to delete the first item in the list but it does not work...
            } else {
                prev->next = list->next;
            }
            return;
        } else {
            prev = list;
            list = list->next;
            first = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

And in the main file for the program:

```
void delete(List *list) {
    printf("key: ");
    char *key;
    key = malloc(sizeof(key)+1);
    readline(key, 128, stdin);

    if(key != NULL) {
        db_delete(key, list);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    delete(list);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: your db_init() function is crude. it should return the malloced list (either by return or by reference parameter)

Comment: Also, in `delete` function you are allocating 5 bytes for `key` (4 bytes for a `sizeof(key)` as `key` is a pointer (`char*`) plus 1. I guess you need to spend more time working on C/C++ and then start to work on more complex topics like linked lists.

Answer (score 1):

There a couple of issues here

First of all you call db_init which allocates an element even when you want to delete one.

Second you need to take into account that if the first element is deleted you need to return the address of the new first element but with your current function you don't do this.

The prototype should look like this instead

```
void db_delete(char *key, List **list)
```

or maybe a bit neater, by returning the first element:

```
List* db_delete(char *key)
```

So the function could look something like this

```
List* db_delete(const char *key, List *list) 
{
  // normally it is not a good idea to use an argument
  // to a function as a loop variable in a function
  // also check arguments to avoid segfaults and 
  // other headaches
  if ( key != NULL && list != NULL )
  {
    List* cur = list;
    List* prev = NULL;

    for ( ; cur != NULL; cur=cur->next )
    {
      // identify if it is the one to delete
      if ( !strcmp(key, cur->key) ) 
      {
        if ( prev != NULL ) // if not first
        {
          List* tmp = cur;
          prev->next = cur->next;
          free(tmp);
          return list;
        }
        else // if first
        {
          List* tmp = cur;
          List* next = cur->next;
          free( tmp );
          return next; 
        }
      }
    }
    prev = cur;
  }
  return list;
}
```

Another tip is to use calloc instead of malloc, then you do not
need to initialize the next,prev since they will already be 0.

Comment: Looks good but the code assumes that there is a prev field in the struct, I am not able to modify the struct to contain that.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your delete function has no way of communicating to the caller that the list now has a new first element.

The best fix is to make it return the new head of the list:

```
List * db_delete(List *list, const char *key);
```

Answer (score 0):

you must change the list Variable in your main. This can be achieved if you pass a pointer to a pointer to your delete function like "delete(List **list)"

Comment: I tried that, but then I would also need to change the call to db_delete to db_delete(key, *database) right? And then in db_delete each occurrence of database would be *database, and then the '->' operator does not work...

Comment: so this: 'list = list->next;', would be this: '*list = (list\*)->next';? I thaught that I would just write it like '*list = *list->next;'